# Splitting a dataset in to datatables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, dataset

I have a software system that I am 'trying' to maintain and upgrade.  I have had no formal c# training and only 1 class of sql.  Most of my limited experience is with Java, C++.  We are using MSSQL 2005.

I have a query run in c# that gets a dataset with 1 table and 15 or so columns.  The number of rows returned is different each time it is ran.  The first column is the storeid.  I need to separate records by storeid in to their own datatable.  Once I have that there is an existing method for sending it out to a CSV file.

So far I have found Datatable.Select, order it by storeid.

One option would be pulling all the unique storeid's from the dataset and putting them into an array.  Then I could query based on existing storeid's and copy or move those rows to a new datatable using a foreach.

If someone could just point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Mark

Comment: It was hard to find your question in your question.

Comment: I need to split a dataset into tables based on values in the first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly a few ways to do this, but something like this should work:

```
        DataSet dsMain = GetMyMainDataSet();
        DataSet dsTablesById = new DataSet();

        foreach (DataRow row in dsMain.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            string storeId = row["storeid"].ToString();
            if (!dsTablesById.Tables.Contains(storeId))
            {
                dsTablesById.Tables.Add(storeId);
                foreach (DataColumn col in dsMain.Tables[0].Columns)
                {
                    dsTablesById.Tables[storeId].Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);
                }
            }
            dsTablesById.Tables[storeId].Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
            dsTablesById.Tables[storeId].AcceptChanges();
        }
```

dsTablesById would contain all of your datatables, each named by your distinct values of storeid.

Comment: It looks like this will work.  Wouldn't it be easier to clone the datatable, I thought clone would copy the original structure without the data.

Comment: Sure, that would be another way to do part of the above answer. That would replace the inner foreach. Just make sure that you keep a way to identify which datatable belongs to which storeid (depending on how you decide to collect your datatables / dataset vs. Dictionary / etc.).

Comment: I am using the dataset the way it is pulled out, that code was written quite some time ago.  I am trying to keep my updates as simple (and maybe drawn out) as I can.

Answer (score 1):

```
if you know number of tables you can use this methode..

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
                dt1 = ds.Tables[0];
                dt2 = ds.Tables[1];
```

Comment: In the Dataset there is only one Datatable, sorry if I wasn't clear on that.  From that datatable I want to split the records based on storeid.  So one datatable will have all of storeid 00001, another will have all recs for storeid 00004.

Answer (score 0):

Order your query by storeid and then loop the datatable in code and create a new table every time the storeid changes. You can also use LINQ to get copy it over or just do so manually.